# Как настроить dkms на игнор -Wmisleading-indentation?

Tags: linux, c, gcc, драйвер

Модуль собирается нормально, но не устанавливается с dkms. Код тут https://github.com/alex-eri/ttypos.git

```
Unpacking ttypos-dkms (303-202012) over (20.12-11) ...
Setting up ttypos-dkms (303-202012) ...
Loading new ttypos-303 DKMS files...
It is likely that 5.4.81-1-lts belongs to a chroot's host
Building for 4.19.0-12-amd64
Building initial module for 4.19.0-12-amd64
Error!  Build of ttypos.ko failed for: 4.19.0-12-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/ttypos/303/build/ for more information.
dpkg: error processing package ttypos-dkms (--install):
 installed ttypos-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 7
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ttypos-dkms
```

/var/lib/dkms/ttypos/303/build/make.log

```
DKMS make.log for ttypos-303 for kernel 4.19.0-12-amd64 (x86_64)
Wed Dec 16 18:59:57 UTC 2020
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-12-amd64'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/ttypos/303/build/ttyPos.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /var/lib/dkms/ttypos/303/build/ttyPos.mod.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/ttypos/303/build/ttyPos.ko
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-12-amd64'
```

Желательно пофиксить со стороны dkms.

Comment: дык, а если пофиксить предупреждение оно заработает?

Comment: пофиксил - всеравно не ставится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ttypos.ko` ожидает `dkms`, а в исходниках `ttyPos.ko`.